# "0923" in firebase taking only 923

Tags: javascript, reactjs

while passing the value to firebase as 0923 but it returns 923. I want the value like same what ever passing.
I tried to fix this issue by using this link. But I did't fix
https://community.kodular.io/t/i-am-getting-different-value-in-firebase-if-i-put-number-in-value/50686

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to save an Int (Number) instead of a String, try saving the value as a string,
e.g `'0923'` instead `0923`

Comment: If we convert to Number means it will pass value to firebase as a 923

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: He is asking you to convert the number to a string. Not the other way round.

Comment: My doubt here is how are you even holding the data on your side? As soon as you convert a string with a leading zero to a number, it gets converted to its octal form if numbers are < 8. So are you holding this variable as a number or as a string before you send it to firebase?

Comment: I passing as a string, why means I want value with 0. like 0923

Comment: But in firebase not taking as a string it is convert to number

Comment: Have you tried logging the value before sending it to firebase? If not please try that and check if it is indeed the string "0923" (or a similar value). I doubt the value you are sending itself is a number.